# SuppressDetectArrayMove in SystemTextJson.JsonDiffPatch nuget package does not work as expected

Tags: system.text.json

I'm using `SystemTextJson.JsonDiffPatch` nuget package to compare `JsonDocument`s. It has a `SuppressDetectArrayMove` flag which, if I understand it correctly, allows to ignore the order of array elements:

```
JsonDiffPatcher.DefaultOptions =
    () => new JsonDiffOptions { SuppressDetectArrayMove = true };

var x = JsonDocument.Parse(@"{""a"":[{""b"":1},{""b"":2}]}");
var y = JsonDocument.Parse(@"{""a"":[{""b"":1},{""b"":2}]}");
var z = JsonDocument.Parse(@"{""a"":[{""b"":2},{""b"":1}]}");

var test1 = x.DeepEquals(y);  //test1 is true
var test2 = x.DeepEquals(z);  //test2 is false, expected true

x.Deserialize<JsonNode>().ShouldEqual(y.Deserialize<JsonNode>());  //no exception
x.Deserialize<JsonNode>().ShouldEqual(z.Deserialize<JsonNode>());  //throws JsonEqualException, expected no exception
```

Is this a bug, or does `SuppressDetectArrayMove` have a different meaning? In this case, what is it, and how can I configure `SystemTextJson.JsonDiffPatch` to ignore the array order?